# Wordpress Loops: Excluding by Tag String, Register by Function?

Tags: wordpress, loops, tags, set

I have 3 loops running on the front page.

One for the slider, and it wants posts that have the tag "slider".

One for featured articles, and it wants posts that have the tag "featured".

And a third I am calling in loop_latest.php, it wants the 6 latest posts; the trick here is those need to be the 6 latests that do NOT have the tags "slider" or "featured".

So I have this query.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
     array( 
              'showposts' => '6',
              'tag_not_in' => array('featured, slider'),
     ) );
```

I'm pretty sure the problem here is that "tag_not_in" doesn't like strings, it wants IDs.

SO! Is there a way to pass it the strings?

If not, how do I divine what the IDs of tags are?

Can I run some code in "functions.php" to set and reserve the ids? featured == 777, slider == 888

Something like that?

I'd like to be able to SET them so that gets packaged with this theme. Rather than have to hope that when the client registers the tags "slider" and "featured" they match up with what I have chosen in the loops/query.

Answer (score 0):

the [correct parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) is `tag__not_in` (with 2 underscores).

additionally - to get your tag ID put this code in your `functions.php`

```
function get_tag_id_by_name($tag_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $tag_ID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->terms." WHERE  `name` =  '".$tag_name."'");

    return $tag_ID;
}
```

and your new code should be:

```
$featuredtag = get_tag_id_by_name('featured');
$slidertag = get_tag_id_by_name('slider');
$query = new WP_Query( 
     array( 
              'showposts' => '6',
              'tag__not_in' => array($featuredtag, $slidertag),
     ) );
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a function to PREregister the id's for "slider" and "featured"?

That way when I ship this theme off then they can become 777 and 888 and I KNOW what they are so I can single them out?

::EDIT::

Looking at your example, this is a much neater solution, as it doesn't matter WHAT the IDs are; we get them, then exclude them. Thank you.